# Pandas: Calculate total timedelta of intermediate time entries

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a dataframe that looks like below

| Date | Name | In/Out | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | Homer | IN | 07:10 |
| **2024-01-01** | **Homer** | **OUT** | **09:30** |
| **2024-01-01** | **Homer** | **IN** | **10:00** |
| 2024-01-01 | Homer | OUT | 16:00 |
| 2024-01-01 | Marge | In | 07:15 |
| 2024-01-01 | Marge | Out | 16:10 |
| 2024-01-01 | Bart | In | 07:14 |
| **2024-01-01** | **Bart** | **Out** | **10:00** |
| **2024-01-01** | **Bart** | **In** | **10:15** |
| **2024-01-01** | **Bart** | **Out** | **12:00** |
| **2024-01-01** | **Bart** | **In** | **12:30** |
| 2024-01-01 | Bart | Out | 17:00 |

My end goal is to calculate the total timedelta (total_seconds()) of intermediate `IN/OUT` times only, as highlighted. Expected output below.

| Date | Name | TimeDelta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | Homer | 1800 |
| 2024-01-01 | Bart | 2700 |

I haven't been to sure where to start with this one and cannot find any examples anywhere else?

example dataframe:

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2024-01-01', 'Homer', 'in', '07:30'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Homer', 'out' ,'09:00'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Homer', 'in' ,'09:30'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Homer', 'out' ,'16:00'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Marge', 'in' , '06:20'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Marge', 'out' ,'16:00'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Bart', 'in' ,'07:10'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Bart', 'out' ,'08:00'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Bart', 'in' ,'08:20'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Bart', 'out' ,'17:00'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Barney', 'in' ,'08:10'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Lisa', 'in' ,'08:05'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Lisa', 'out' ,'14:00'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Lisa', 'in' ,'14:15'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Lisa', 'out' ,'18:10'],
    ['2024-01-01', 'Millhouse', 'out' ,'19:10'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Homer', 'in', '07:30'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Homer', 'out' ,'09:00'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Marge', 'in' , '06:30'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Marge', 'out' ,'09:10'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Marge', 'in' ,'10:10'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Marge', 'out' ,'16:10'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Bart', 'in' ,'07:10'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Bart', 'out' ,'15:00'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Barney', 'in' ,'08:10'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Lisa', 'in' ,'08:05'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Lisa', 'out' ,'16:00'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Millhouse', 'in' ,'08:10'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Millhouse', 'in' ,'08:10'],
    ['2024-02-01', 'Millhouse', 'in' ,'16:15']],
    columns=['Date', 'Name', 'In/Out', 'Time'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Time is sorted within a group, that the first In/Out is always In, and that In/Out are always alternating.

You could convert the times [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) to compute the [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), ignore the first/last value (with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)) and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) the "IN" timedeltas before converting to [`total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
# cleanup IN/OUT format
df['In/Out'] = df['In/Out'].str.upper()

out = (df
  .assign(dt=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M'))
  .groupby(['Date', 'Name'])
  .apply(lambda g: 
         g['dt'].diff().iloc[1:-1]
         [g['In/Out'].eq('IN')]
         .sum().total_seconds())
  .reset_index(name='TimeDelta')
  .query('TimeDelta>0') # optional: remove rows with null TimeDelta
)
```

Output:

```
         Date       Name  TimeDelta
1  2024-01-01   J Bloggs     1800.0
2  2024-01-01  M Simpson     2700.0
```

---

*NB. If any of the initial assumptions is incorrect, you just need to pre-process the data to sort it and remove invalid rows.*

Example:

```
# cleanup IN/OUT format
df['In/Out'] = df['In/Out'].str.upper()

m1 = df.sort_values(by='Time').groupby(['Date', 'Name'])['In/Out'].shift(-1).ne(df['In/Out'])

out = (df[m1]
  .assign(dt=pd.to_datetime(df.loc[m1, 'Time'], format='%H:%M'))
  .groupby(['Date', 'Name'])
  .apply(lambda g: 
         g['dt'].diff().iloc[1:-1]
         [g['In/Out'].eq('IN')]
         .sum().total_seconds())
  .reset_index(name='TimeDelta')
  .query('TimeDelta>0') # optional: remove rows with null TimeDelta
)
```

Output:

```
          Date   Name  TimeDelta
1   2024-01-01   Bart     1200.0
2   2024-01-01  Homer     1800.0
3   2024-01-01   Lisa      900.0
10  2024-02-01  Marge     3600.0
```

Comment: Thanks, its very close.
In/Out is not always consistent and time is not sorted, how would i pre-process before utilizing your answer?

Comment: Can you provide an additional example? As `DataFrame` constructor please for better reproducibility.

Comment: `DataFrame` example added

Comment: @Brunch1012 see update (please also provide the expected output in the question)

Answer (score -1):

I would convert your dataframe so that each record was on person on day X with an in time and an out time.  Then you can just calculate the delta from those two times.  Here is how I would do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import random as rd
names=['John','Jeff']
dates=['01/01/2024','01/02/2024']
intimes=['08:00','09:00']
outtimes=['17:00','17:30']

namelist=[]
datelist=[]
inlist=[]
outlist=[]

for i in names:
    for j in dates:
        namelist.append(i)
        datelist.append(j)
        inlist.append(rd.sample(intimes,1)[0])
        outlist.append(rd.sample(outtimes,1)[0])
        
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Name']=namelist
df['Date']=datelist
df['In']=inlist
df['Out']=outlist

df['InDateandTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+' '+df['In'])
df['OutDateandTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+' '+df['Out'])

df['TimeDelta']=df['OutDateandTime']-df['InDateandTime']


display(df)
```

And here is the output:

[image]

You just need to make a new dataframe that converts your records to a single record per person per day and then apply this method to that dataframe.  You will need to combine the dates and times as strings first and then use pd.DateTime to convert them to DateTime.  I have shown how to do this in the code.  You can also drop the original 'Date', 'In' and 'Out' columns but I left them to show you exactly what I did.  Much of the code is just creating a dataset that I could use as an example.